# .htaccess: remove index.php and redirect www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to achieve 2 things with my .htaccess:

1) Remove the index.php from the URL (website.com/index.php/clases/ to website.com/clases/ )
2) Redirect all the URL's from website.com -> www.website.com

The problem: is that when I enter, website.com it redirects me to www.website.com/index.php insted of just the URL without the index.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Options All -Indexes

#RewriteBase /var/www/html/ci_yosoyprofe/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|uploads|assets|t|html|tmp|images|systems\/plugins|static|robots\.txt|css\/)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your rule like this:

```
Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|uploads|assets|t|html|tmp|images|systems/plugins|static|robots\.txt|css/)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```